# sharepoint Claim Based Auth FBA custom logout not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fba

Hello i am new in sharepoint development. I am working on an application in which we are using FBA. For logout purpose we are using a custom logout page and on that page we are clearing everything session, cookies. Now when a user is loggedIn one can use this tool http://portswigger.net/burp/ to copy and save cookies and entire session data of loggedIn user. Now after logout this can be easily use to loggedin a user again. Nothing worked for me, though i have expired auth cookies while logout. any suggestion how to make a user not able to loggedIn with cookies saved through the burp tool..

Answer (score 0):

You can issue an encrypted cookie that would store the session ID. Add a control to the header of the site that would compare the encrypted header to the current header. If they don't match, sent the FedAuth cookie to expire now.